# IIFE breaks interceptor - unknown provider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-injector

I'm using an interceptor to add JWT tokens to my http calls. My code works fine like this:

```
angular
    .module("jwtKickStart")
    .factory("authInterceptorService", authInterceptorService);

authInterceptorService.$inject = ["$injector", "$q", "$timeout"];
function authInterceptorService($injector, $q, $timeout) {

    var $state, loginModal, $http;

    //...
```

But if I wrap that in an IIFE, then I get an Unknown Provider error:

```
(function () {
"use strict";

angular
    .module("jwtKickStart")
    .factory("authInterceptorService", authInterceptorService);

authInterceptorService.$inject = ["$injector", "$q", "$timeout"];
function authInterceptorService($injector, $q, $timeout) {

    var $state, loginModal, $http;

    //...
```

Am I not allowed to use the IIFE?

EDIT: here are some more details

The error message is this one: http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.8/$injector/unpr?p0=authInterceptorServiceProvider%20%3C-%20authInterceptorService%20%3C-%20%24http%20%3C-%20%24templateFactory%20%3C-%20%24view%20%3C-%20%24state

The source code is available here:
https://github.com/capesean/JWTKickStart/tree/master/JWTKickStart.APP/app

Comment: can you provide the full error message and more codes?

Comment: why are you wrapping in an IIFE?

Comment: @ps0604 I'm trying to follow John Papa's style guidelines, which use IFFEs everywhere (as far as I can tell). If there's a reason NOT to, then sure. I just didn't expect it to break the code.

Answer (score 0):

try to inject like this :

```
(function () {
"use strict";

angular
    .module("jwtKickStart")
    .factory("authInterceptorService",["$injector","$q","$timeout" authInterceptorService]);

function authInterceptorService($injector, $q, $timeout) {
// your code
}
```